Filter Expression for nested Arrays using JsonPath
I am trying to filter within nested json array.
My sample source json is:
{
    "identifier": [
        {
            "type": {
                "coding": [
                    {
                        "system": "http://fhir.de/CodeSystem/identifier-type-de-basis",
                        "code": "GKV"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "system": "http://fhir.de/sid/gkv/kvid-10",
            "value": "A123456789"
        },
        {
            "use": "secondary",
            "type": {
                "coding": [
                    {
                        "system": "http://fhir.de/CodeSystem/identifier-type-de-basis",
                        "code": "PKV"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "value": "1234567890",
            "assigner": {
                "display": "Test PKV AG"
            }
        }
    ],
    "active": true
}

Now I want to select the element value of the first identifier entry using this json path expression:
$.identifier[?(@.type.coding[?(@.code == 'GKV')])].value

As result I get an arry of both identifier values: ["A123456789", "1234567890"].
But I expected to get only the first of these both values.
So how I have to write the json path expression to get only the first value (the order of the array entry is not deterministic. So I cannot use an array index expression)
Regards Marco

It might the the lib that you're using.  The path you have works as you expect on mine.  You can test it at https://json-everything.net/json-path.
